# How to Configure Jmeter for after Login process in an Application?

Tags: jmeter

How to Configure Jmeter for after Login process in an Application?

I am able to configure the login request for 100 users from the CSV file with the help of Jmeter's "CSV Data set Config", but after the successful login of all I want to know how to configure the jmeter to go to the "Offers" page of there(100 user) accounts.Means 1 User can login & View his/her "Offer" page.Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to achieve this scenario:

1. add another HTTP sampler & fill the details like Server IP, Path of Offers URL (you will have already done the same for Login), HTTP Header data etc. and pass correlation parameters from the response of Login if required to view the offers specific to 1 user.

   make sure you use right ***method*** (GET/POST) in HTTP Sampler.
2. record the whole scenario (ref: http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf).
   You will still have to do the correlation of parameters (using regular expression extractor or Xpath extractor) wherever required. This entirely depends on the parameters required for the offer page HTTP request.

hope this will help.

Comment: OK, & how to pass correlation parameters from the response of login?

Comment: refer  http://artoftesting.com/performanceTesting/correlation.html
you can also find other resources, please search in google.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a cookie manager to store the session and cookie for all logged in users.

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager